# Rendering a textured quad not working

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl, texture2d

So, I'm making a 2D game using lwjgl, and rendering a textured quad won't work.
I have 3 textures, names are :

```
DirtTexture.png, GrassTexture.png, WaterTexture.png
```

All are located inside of the "res" package.

My code is this :

```
    public static void DrawQuadTex(Texture tex, float x, float y, float width, float height) {

    tex.bind();
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(width, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(width, height);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, height);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnd();

}

public static Texture LoadTexture(String path, String fileType) {

    Texture tex = null;
    InputStream in = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
    try {
        tex = TextureLoader.getTexture(fileType, in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tex;

}
```

It's called like this :

```
public class Boot {

public Boot() {

    BeginSession();

    Texture t = LoadTexture("res/GrassTexture.png", "PNG");
    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

        DrawQuadTex(t, 0, 0, 64, 64);

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);

    }

    Display.destroy();

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Boot();
    }

}
```

My problem is that it renders a white texture, even though my selected textures are not white.
Anyone knows why? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but displaying 2 images at the same time fixed the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clear the screen before drawing using:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

tex.bind();
glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
...
```